# Genymotion does not start.

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion

On device start it thinking long time, then gives:
[image: Startup error]

VirtualBox shows info like this:
[image: Virtual image screen]

In logs:

```
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion] [Debug] Starting player at  "/home/nord/Programms/genymotion" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [ADB] Use Genymotion Android tools: "/home/nord/Programms/genymotion/tools/adb" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Warning] Unable to load translations. Falling back to english 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  **** 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Warning] Player version: 2.2.0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] Chipset: "GenuineIntel" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] CPUID 0x1 (Intel): ECX= "7fbae3bf" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [VBoxManageCore] Path: "VBoxManage" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostinfo") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 4 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 2 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] [System properties] Max memory size: 7850 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("list", "hostonlyifs") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("--version") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VM engine version: "4.3.10_Ubuntur93012" 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Sony Xperia Z - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "Sony Xperia Z - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Sony Xperia Z - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920") returns 0 
апр 28 00:16:21 [Genymotion Player] [Debug] VBoxManage ("showvminfo", "Sony Xperia Z - 4.3 - API 18 - 1080x1920") returns 0
```

Genymotion version 2.2.0, VirtualBox is 4.3.10.

Comment: Could u solved this issue? I`ve also faced.

Comment: No, I couldn't, I've installed Windows for Android development.

Answer (score 5):

For me, this problem was caused by Cisco Anyconnect VPN being connected (or having been connected since I've cleared my VirtualBox Host-Only network "vboxnet0" again).

Basically, what appears to happen is connecting to VPN immediately screws up my VirtualBox's Host-Only "vboxnet0" network.  Even if I disconnect from VPN, I am unable to start Genymotion until I do the following (this fixes the MAJORITY of all issues starting Genymotion, by the way):

1. Open VirtualBox
2. Go to Preferences (CMD + , on the Mac, CTRL + G on the PC)
3. go to Networks (and on Mac, also click on Host-Only Networks)
4. Highlight the host-only adapter ("vboxnet0" on Mac, "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter" on PC)
5. Click the Remove icon (to the right of the list of adapters, the center icon with the minus symbol on the network card icon)
6. Press OK and close VirtualBox

NOTE: I have NEVER gotten Genymotion to start up while VPN is connected!  Cisco Anyconnect appears to want to direct all of the host-only emulator traffic through its tunnel and off into nowheresland, is my best guess.  You MUST be disconnected from VPN in order to use Genymotion!  (At least, until someone figures out and shares how to tell Anyconnect to ignore the VirtualBox vboxnet0 network completely, which I have no idea how to do)

Also: WORTH IT!  Android AVD emulators are terrible, even with the Intel HAXM enhancement...Genymotion is so much better, I develop Android for a living and it has made my life so much easier :D

EDIT: Including command line solution from malcubierre:
`VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet0`

Comment: I had similar issues (albeit on Windows) and I have been able to use Genymotion finally the way I wanted. Thanks

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear I'm helping at least one person never have to deal with the Android AVD emulators ever again!

Comment: I did not find this button, I deleted adapter by command: VBoxManage hostonlyif remove vboxnet1 (replace vboxnet1 by your adapter name). Finally it worked!

Comment: NOTE: I haven't needed to do this on my Mac for quite some time. I am uncertain if this is due to a recent update to any of the following:  my VPN software, VirtualBox, or Genymotion